# How do you run/call a module in another module in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, module, call, vba

Okay so i have 3 modules. My first module is "main" that is the module that i need to call the other module. What i mean is that when i run main, i want it to `call/run` the other 2 module. Currently when i press F5, it doesn't do this.  How do i do this?

My current code looks like this:

```
Sub main_TRY()
    Call Module2
    Call Module3
End Sub
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are the `Sub` or `Function` definitions called `Module2` and `Module3`? You want to `Call TheActualSubroutineName`, not the module containing the code. For example, you would want `Call main_TRY`, not `Call Module1`

Comment: oh. okay i solved it already. Thanks @Dan Wagner

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer:

```
Sub main_TRY1()
    Call Module2.Formating
    Call Module3.Data
End Sub
```

Comment: That is only necessary if **Formatting** and **Data** were declared as *Private Sub*. A *Public Sub* is the default so if they were declared as `Public Sub Formating(...)` or `Sub Formating(...)` then `Call Formating(...)` or simply `Formating(...)`  is appropriate. The `(...)` is not needed unless you are throwing parameters into the sub.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped. After I removed _Private_ from my function definitions, I was able to call them from another module. And I did not need to include the module name in the call to my (now public) function.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simular struction on one of my vba-scripts, and it goes like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call GetData1
End Sub
```

and in my module2, it looks like this

```
Sub GetData1()
'my code
Dim IE As Object
Dim dd As Variant

Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

IE.Visible = False

IE.Navigate "https://www.avanza.se/aktier/om-aktien.html/5247/investor-b"

Application.StatusBar = "Loading, Please wait..."

IEWait IE

Application.StatusBar = "Searching for value. Please wait..."
dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("lastPrice SText bold")(0).innerText
Range("G7").Value = dd
End Sub
```

Maybe a bit to much, but I just wanted you to understand the structure of the code I'm using.

So everytime I click the buttom "CommandButton1"
This code above will execute, but in your case everytime you call the function main_try() , you should, as pointed out above, call on the functions in the modules, not the module itself.

Hoped it helped, best regards

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I needed to call a "Private Sub" routine.
I decided to go with having each module call to the next.
This allowed me to call the first module, then it would run code and trigger the next module if successful, and so on.

```
Sub main_TRY()
    Application.Run ("ModuleNameHere")
End Sub
```

Just add the following to the end of each module and have it call to the next module you would like to run "NextModuleNameHere":

```
    Application.Run ("NextModuleNameHere")
```